# Pandas Open CSV works fine in Linux but not in macOS

Tags: python, linux, macos, pandas

I'm reading a .csv file that looks like this:

```
Rank,Full Journal Title,JCR Abbreviated Title,ISSN,Total Cites,Journal Impact Factor,Impact Factor without Journal Self Cites,5-Year Impact Factor,Immediacy Index,Citable Items,Cited Half-Life,Citing Half-life,Eigenfactor Score,Article Influence Score,% Articles in Citable Items,,Average Journal Impact Factor Percentile,Normalized Eigenfactor
8,Agronomy for Sustainable Development,AGRON SUSTAIN DEV,1774-0746,"2,842",4.101,3.747,4.746,0.455,66,4.9,7.7,0.005670,1.123,53.030,,84.182,0.65038
9,International Journal of Precision Engineering and Manufacturing-Green Technology,INT J PR ENG MAN-GT,2288-6206,329,3.494,2.719,3.494,0.375,48,2.1,6.1,0.001140,0.888,87.500,,83.060,0.13037
```

My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

I was working with Python 2.7 in an Ubuntu desktop and everything worked fine. However, when I run the exactly same code in my macbook pro, it doesn't work. The output in my macbook is:

```
[IN]: raw_data.iloc[8]
[OUT]:
Rank                                                                                        
9
Full Journal Title                          International Journal of 
Precision Engineering...
JCR Abbreviated Title                                                     
INT J PR ENG MAN-GT
ISSN                                                                                
2288-6206
Total Cites                                                                               
329
Journal Impact Factor                                                                   
3.494
Impact Factor without Journal Self Cites                                                
2.719
5-Year Impact Factor                                                                    
3.494
Immediacy Index                                                                         
0.375
Citable Items                                                                              
48
Cited Half-Life                                                                           
2.1
Citing Half-life                                                                          
6.1
Eigenfactor Score                                                                     
0.00114
Article Influence Score                                                                 
0.888
% Articles in Citable Items                                                              
87.5
Unnamed: 15                                                                               
NaN
Average Journal Impact Factor Percentile                                                
83.06
Normalized Eigenfactor                                                                
0.13037
```

That works fine and is the expected output. However, with some lines does not work

```
[IN]: raw_data.iloc[9]
[OUT]:
Rank                                        10,JOURNAL OF INDUSTRIAL 
ECOLOGY,J IND ECOL,10...
Full Journal Title                                                                        
NaN
JCR Abbreviated Title                                                                     
NaN
ISSN                                                                                      
NaN
Total Cites                                                                               
NaN
Journal Impact Factor                                                                     
NaN
Impact Factor without Journal Self Cites                                                  
NaN
5-Year Impact Factor                                                                      
NaN
Immediacy Index                                                                           
NaN
Citable Items                                                                             
NaN
Cited Half-Life                                                                           
NaN
Citing Half-life                                                                          
NaN
Eigenfactor Score                                                                         
NaN
Article Influence Score                                                                   
NaN
% Articles in Citable Items                                                               
NaN
Unnamed: 15                                                                               
NaN
Average Journal Impact Factor Percentile                                                  
NaN
Normalized Eigenfactor                                                                    
NaN
```

Why does my code work with some lines but not with others?? I didn't have this problem in Ubuntu... How can I solve this?????

Thank you!

Comment: The next question is what is your python, pandas and numpy versions? It looks like you are running some duff version, also como estai? I lived in Santiago de Chile 15 years ago. You should be able to do `pd.show_versions()` from both and see the difference

Comment: Numpy: 1.11.0 / Pandas: 0.19.1 / Python: 2.7.11. I'm la raja, thank you

Comment: I can load this fine using pandas `0.21.0` and numpy `1.11.3`, something I did notice is that you have embedded thousands separators in your data: "2,842" for instance, can you try `pd.read_csv('file.csv', thousands=',')`

Comment: I had already solved the thousands problem. However, it still doesn't work the code :/

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but you have an empty column name here: `% Articles in Citable Items,,Average Journal ` there is an empty name here

Comment: I know that I have an empty column. I think it's a problem of the database :/